# Show wordpress post content on mobile

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress, webview

I'd need to show content wordpress page in my Android/iOS application:
I can extract html content post through a simple query and JSON rest

```
SELECT post_content FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'page' and post_name = 'no-event-page'
```

So i can retrieve html to load, but wordpress classes don't work.
For example,

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Today I have no events</p>
<img class="wp-image-1047 aligncenter" src="http://www.joyfriend.it/svil_v2/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/logo-300x300.png" alt="" width="68" height="68" />
```

shows text correctly, but the image is not align centered because "wp-image-1047" class is ignored.

How can I load, for example in a iOS WebView **ONLY THE CONTENT** of a wordpress page?

Thank you for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Incorporate my WordPress Blogs into an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584117/how-can-i-incorporate-my-wordpress-blogs-into-an-ios-app)